# How can you implement the Stairway pattern with an Entity Framework Core solution?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework-core, projects-and-solutions

So...  I'm trying to follow the stairway pattern in a .Net Core Entity Framework project.  I'm using EF Core 2.1.

My Solution Structure is:

```
MyApp.Api    
    MyApp.Data
    MyApp.Data.Interfaces
    MyApp.Logic
    MyApp.Logic.Interfaces
```

e.g. the API (as dependency root) depends on all the rest, but the other projects only depend on abstractions.

```
MyApp.Data  
    MyApp.Data.Interfaces
MyApp.Logic
    MyApp.Logic.Interfaces
    MyApp.Data.Interfaces
```

I've got a complex data model, with child navigation properties.  The problem I'm having is the input json matches the schema of the complex type, but isn't deemed valid when it hits the validation/model-binding stage (i.e. it doesn't hit the Action method).  If I remove the child props, it accepts it as valid input (I'm using the [FromBody] attribute, btw).

For reference, here's the Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] House house)
{
    var item = houseService.Add(house);
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetById", new { id = item.Id }, item);
}
```

The problem code is in the MyApp.Data project (which only has a reference to the MyApp.Data.Interfaces project).  For the child/navigation props I'm using interfaces, like so:

```
// MyApp.Data.Interfaces
public interface IHouse 
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    IEnumerable<IRoom> Rooms {get;set;}    
}

public interface IRoom
{
    int Windows {get;set;}
}

// MyApp.Data
using MyApp.Data.Interfaces;

public class House : IHouse 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<IRoom> Rooms {get;set;}
}
```

If I post some Json to that endpoint, I get an error:

```
{
    "name": "Dunroamin",
    "rooms": [
        {
            "windows": 2
        }
    ]
}

HTTP 400: Bad Request
{
    "rooms[0].windows": [
        "The input was not valid."
    ]
}
```

If I change the code to the following (replace the child property's interface with a concrete type), the error goes away.

```
// MyApp.Data.Interfaces
using MyApp.Data;

public interface IHouse 
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    IEnumerable<Room> Rooms {get;set;}    
}

public interface IRoom
{
    int Windows {get;set;}
}

// MyApp.Data
using MyApp.Data.Interfaces;

public class House : IHouse 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Room> Rooms {get;set;}
}
```

But this violates the stairway pattern, because I'm using a concrete type in my MyApp.Data.Interfaces project.  Interface libraries shouldn't have dependencies on anything, really.  I've seen an implied reference to difficulty when it comes to EF Core and the stairway pattern, but no suggestion of a solution.  I can see the problem is with EF needing a concrete type in order to map it to a SQL query, but how can these two things co-exist?  Is it worth it?

*I'm not committed to this architecture, btw, I just wanted to practice using it again and I'm stubborn, so am willing to make it work for the sake of it...*

Comment: There is no need to abstract the data. Normally you don't use `IString`, `IBool`, `IInt` etc. as method argumenst / return types, why would you do that for complex data (basically DTO). Thus `MyApp.Data.Interfaces` (hence `IHouse`, `IRoom`) are redundant IMHO.

Comment: Are you asking why am I using the Stairway Pattern?  Or are you saying that I'm taking the pattern too far?  I can't see how, if so.  Could you explain a bit more?  Perhaps with your own model of the architecture (that supports Stairway, if possible). BTW, this is a simplified model, just to show the basic nature of the problem.  I'm just trying to apply the Stairway pattern.  My question is how are the models shared across projects without giving their concrete implementations?  i.e.  How is it possible to use abstractions while also satisfying EF?

Comment: Ah, I see I've gone too far.  It's normal to share the POCOs in interface projects (I was taking things too literally, as usual!).  Thanks for the hint, @IvanStoev

Comment: So I guess this question can be closed as not-reproducible?

Comment: @GertArnold  Fine by me!  I can't see an option for 'not reproducible', so haven't closed it myself (the options aren't relevant ad don't want to incorrectly assign it).

Comment: It's one of the off-topic options.

Comment: @GertArnold  Thanks.  Voted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard one, hope this helps. At the beginning may look repetitive, but in long term is the best thing to do so Models and Entities can be autonomous have their own implementation and variables and to expose only what is needed so we also provide a secure solution.
Also 100% adaptive so you can remove the old domain implementation and reference it to the new domain implementation totally sure that the service is not going to fail because a missing reference or concrete class.

[API]
MyApp.Web

```
ref -- >> MyApp.Services (will resolve the abstractions)
ref -- >> MyApp.Domain (will resolve the abstractions)

HomeModel : IHomeModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string ToJson() { }
}
```

I create the reference create my own object to expose it in the Controller with its own properties and needs, then I can map it to the service model and pass it.
I added the reference to domain in case I want to use dependency Injection if needed when the MyApp.Service receives an MyApp.Domain.Abstraction object as argument in the constructor.

[Service]

MyApp.Services.Abstractions (Not necessarily interfaces)

```
IHomeModel 
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}
IHomeService
{
   void Update(IHomeModel model);
}
```

Here I just define the behavior of the service, the model required to perform the operations.

MyApp.Services

```
ref -- >> MyApp.Domain.Abstractions
ref -- >> MyApp.Services.Abstractions

HomeService : IHomeService
{
    public void Update(IHomeModel model);
}
internal Home : IHome { }
internal HomeModel : IHomeModel 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public void ValidateBusinessRule() { }
   internal static IHome ToEntity() { }
}
```

Here I implement both steps so I can freely use the data model to perform any operation required in the services, for example a business rule, constraint anything that the domain is not aware of but the service does.

Then I need to create my concrete type to map the data and pass it to the domain layer, you can use AutoMapper but the bigger issue with it is the problem when you have Methods in the interface, works amazingly when you work only with POCOs or only properties. But at the end is the same, it create a class, create the instance all of this at runtime, you can do it at design time and reduce that time and complexity.

[Domain]

MyApp.Domain.Abstractions (Not necessarily interfaces)

```
IHome 
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here I defined what I want to expose publicly to higher steps.

MyApp.Domain.

```
ref -- >> MyApp.Domain.Abstractions

Home : IHome 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime Created { get; set; }
   public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

In my domain I can work with created and last update properties or save any other value I don't want to share with higher steps.

In summary, the main problem is when we try to "save" time and effort writing classes on each implementation project so we want to share the same instance from Web to Domain.
You will see your projects to grow in number of classes and types, but will decrease dramatically the size of packages needed on each project, the lines of code needed to "fit" the service with domain logic and so on...

The other one is to share the "Entity" in the abstractions project but again that will break the pattern.